# NCover Nunit CruiseControl.NET Task with NCover Addin

Tags: nunit, cruisecontrol.net, ncover

Can someone provide me a sample for a ncover task for a nunit dll?

Answer (score 5):

http://madcoderspeak.blogspot.com/2006/01/code-coverage-with-ncover-from-nunit.html
http://madcoderspeak.blogspot.com/2006/06/integrating-ncover-code-coverage-with.html

Maybe a bit dated.. but HTH